# how to assign a new key and value to an object already defined in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

I'm migrating from js to ts, and I'm doing this by creating a discord bot in typescript (to understand the environment).
and when trying to create new keys on an object already created by a class I am getting error of `Property 'key' does not exist on type 'object'`

code example:

```js
import { Client } from "discord.js";
const client = new Client({
  intents: [permissions],
});
client.handler = new CommandManager()
//error: Property 'handler' does not exist on type 'Client<boolean>'
```

which is strange to me, because in javascript you can assign new keys to an object already created.
i tried with Object.assign()

```js
Object.assign(client, { handler: new CommandManager() })
```

and initially it worked, the key was actually inside the object when I used console.log(), but when I tried to call that value in code, the same error was returned.

```js
Object.assign(client, { handler: new CommandManager() })
console.log(client)
//has .handler object inside it
client.handler.stuff
//error: Property 'handler' does not exist on type 'Client<boolean>'
```

I would like to understand why this occurs and if there is a solution to assign keys inside an object so I can use it in code

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by creating a custom client class which extends discord's client class.

```
import { Client, ClientOptions } from 'discord.js';

class CustomClient extends Client {
  handler: CommandManager = new CommandManager()
  constructor(options: ClientOptions){
    super(options);
  }
}
```